# How to convert PDF file to KML file

Tags: pdf, kml

Is there a way to convert a map pdf file to a kml file? How can I convert it or is there any guidelines to do so?

Comment: Depends on the content. Does PDF contain ground overlay images to map to KML or a set of latitude/longitude coordinates ?? Are you looking for a solution using Java or python or something else entirely?

Comment: It contains both and a solution in java or just something to convert it?

Comment: Why do people down vote my question?

Comment: Because it's not suited to Stack Overflow. Surely there is **a** way, even if you have to program everything from scratch. Guidelines? You want a step-by-step walkthrough?

Answer (score 1):

[Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) is an open source Java library that can parse PDF document and extract content. The API includes methods to extract text, metadata, and embedded files from PDF files as well create PDF files from scratch. Apache PDFBox also includes several command-line utilities. One command-line tool called *pdfbox-app* has options to extract all text or images from PDF files.

There is also [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) library which focuses solely on text extraction from a variety of file formats including PDF.